# Start CSS-Animation at x-Percent

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a CSS-Animation:

```
@keyframes{
    from{left: 0%;}
    to{left: 80%;}
}
```

Now I want to start playing the animation for example at 63%. Not left = 63%, rather at 63% of the animation. So the element starts to move at (80*0.63 = 50.4) left = 50.4%;. If this is not possible, then is it possible to change the keyframes with javascript?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 4):

you could use [negative animation delay](https://css-tricks.com/css-animation-tricks/#article-header-id-1) to jump to your desired step. you must calculate the timing from the original animation time and set that as a negative animation-delay.

Answer (score 1):

I'm calculating the negative animation delay value, in milliseconds.

```
-1000 - (-1000 * .63) = -370
```

So, we're going `370ms` back from the beginning (a second), which is 63% through the 1 second duration of the animation. This calculation is dependent on knowing the animation duration ahead of time.

```css
@keyframes moveBox {
  from {
    left: 0%;
  }
  to {
    left: 80%;
  }
}

.box {
  --negative-delay: calc(-1000ms - (-1000ms * .63));
  --duration: 1000ms;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;  
  animation: moveBox var(--duration) forwards var(--negative-delay);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdgf9en0/7/)

Comment: This feels just the right amount of elegant given we don’t officially have something like `animation-start-at`.

I’m using this approach with `animation-play-state: paused` for `prefers-reduced-motion` to make sure they’re at their starting point when not animating.